# OSError: [Errno 26] Text file busy: 'baremetrics'

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, vagrant-windows, vagrant-provision, vagrant-plugin

I am getting the following error after running `vagrant provision`.

> OSError: [Errno 26] Text file busy: 'baremetrics'
> [text file busy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4TDKT.png)

I am using Virtual box : 6.1.16 version and vagrant : 2.2.14 version.
Help me to solve this error.

Answer (score 0):

This error is caused by a [bug](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/19004) in recent versions of the VirtualBox Guest Additions for Linux on Windows hosts. It has not been fixed upstream as of this writing, but you may be able to work around it by downgrading VirtualBox Guest Additions to 6.0.4. To do this, create a `~/.[appname]-vagrant-config` file and add this line:

> VBOXADD_VERSION 6.0.4

Then run these commands (yes, reload is needed twice):

> vagrant plugin install vagrant-vbguest
>
> vagrant reload
>
> vagrant reload --provision